# Add-Content with a Select-String as the added content?

Tags: powershell

My intention is to look within a text file (C:\Users\pmaddox\Desktop\VaughnResers eligibility text.txt) and find the specific date and enter the entire line that contained said date into a second file (VaughnReserBatTest.txt). I hoped to accomplish this by using Add-Content's format (location "input") with Select-String's piped Select-Object Line to bring the raw string from the text line into the Add-Content cmdlet but thus far I am having now luck...

My current script looks like this:

```
Add-Content \\Waqmed1\pmaddox$\VaughnReserBatTest.txt Select-String  C:\Users\pmaddox\Desktop\VaughnResers eligibility text.txt  -pattern "10/11/1988" | Select-Object Line
```

I am fairly new to powershell and I believe my answer lies somewhere in either the "create and object" direction or the "fix your damn code" direction. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the file that contains the desired line is named a.txt and the file you want to write the desired line to is named b.txt:

```
Get-Content .\a.txt | Select-String "10/11/1988" | Add-Content .\b.txt
```

Note that all matching lines frorm a.txt will be written to b.txt, so if there is more than one match then you will write multiple entries to b.txt. If you only want the first match, you can use the following:

```
Get-Content .\a.txt | Select-String "10/11/1988"  | Select-Object -First 1 | Add-Content .\b.txt
```

Comment: Thank you! Very concise but informative! I think I was thinking about the pipes in more of a C programming sense than a scripting sense, looking at it now makes perfect sense however. Thanks again to both of you!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
get-contentc "C:\Users\pmaddox\Desktop\VaughnResers eligibility text.txt" |
select-string -Pattern '10/11/1988' ) | select -expa line | 
add-content \\Waqmed1\pmaddox$\VaughnReserBatTest.txt
```

Comment: I don't think the property expansion of "line" is needed because Add-Content accepts an Object[] in its Value parameter.

Comment: @dugas In my test without `-expand` I add `@{Line=test date 01/11/2012}. Maybe just in my test.. :)

Comment: Yes, you are correct. If you pipe to select-object and select line, it needs to be expanded.

Comment: @dugas Try using exactly my code `| select line |` and `| select -expa line|` you'll see the different behavior... It's the `select-object` totally unneeded in this case! I like your first example code!